# How use tickInterval with categories.push in the Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need set my xAxis to datetime for use correctly the tickInterval.

In my example, i used it for setting my category:

```
 options.xAxis.categories.push(Date.UTC(2010, 3, 4,12,10));
```

But, I cannot use the tickInterval, the Highchart read my serie like a normal categories (not datetime) but I used type: 'datetime' on the xAxis.

My code is in:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ghhf/172/

Answer (score 0):

Use: `options.xAxis.tickPositions.push(Date.UTC(2010, 3, 4,12,10));`

And make sure that your axis is `type:'datetime'` and categories are removed.